# Resetting is not working properly in fr:currency

Tags: orbeon

I am using orbeon 3.9 CE and I'm using fr:currency for Currency field.I ve a scenario like having '100000' as default value for currency field and if field is empty, then it should return default value.

Probelm:at 1st time, if we make currency field as empty from default value(100000), then it returns to default value but afterwards it doesn't return to default value.While saving, it saves default value.Sample code:

```
<xforms:instance id="abc">
<currency-1>100000</currency-1>
</xforms:instance>

<xforms:bind id="currency-1" nodeset=""
 calculate="if(sonme condition) then (if(.='') then '100000.00' else .) else '100000'"
constraint=""/>

<fr:currency bind="currency-1">
</fr:currency>
```